# Odd problem - Form won't close when opening new form using WHERE

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have two forms (in question here).  `frmContactList` and `frmContactDetails`.  `frmContactList` is a datasheet list of last names, first names, and e-mail addresses.  The idea (which works and hasn't been a problem so far) is that when you double-click either the last name or the first name, the form `frmContactDetails` is opened to the specific record chosen on `frmContactList`.  All this works just fine.  Where I'm having the trouble (annoyingly) is I want it to OPEN `frmContactDetails` then CLOSE frmContactList.  OPEN works fine, close doesn't happen until I close `frmContactDetails`, though.

I *BELIEVE* the error is with the fact that I started with a "*prefab*" Access template and went to editing it from there.  I didn't create this project from scratch.  *Won't make that mistake again*.  Thought I'd save time.  Yeah right...

Here's the `DblClick()` coding I'm using for the Last Name (First Name will be the same once I figure out the *bug*:
**NOTE:** I commented out the `Form.Dirty` and Macro Error code because it's part of that messy "*prefab*" Access stuff.

```
Private Sub Last_Name_DblClick(Cancel As Integer)
On Error GoTo Last_Name_DblClick_Err

    On Error Resume Next
'    If (Form.Dirty) Then
'        DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdSaveRecord
'    End If
'    If (MacroError.Number <> 0) Then
'        Beep
'        MsgBox MacroError.Description, vbOKOnly, ""
'        Exit Sub
'    End If

    DoCmd.OpenForm "frmContactDetails", acNormal, "", "[ID]=" & ID, , acDialog
    DoCmd.Close acForm, "frmContactList"

Last_Name_DblClick_Exit:
    Exit Sub

Last_Name_DblClick_Err:
    MsgBox Error$
    Resume Last_Name_DblClick_Exit

End Sub
```

Here are a few pictures of the design.
Simple design.
[image: Just a quick image of the design of the data in question - proving there is an "ID" field.]
Here `frmContactDetails` is opened (personal information is blacked out) showing `frmContactList` in the background not closed.
[image: Image of both forms]

Comment: Try changing the order of those 2 lines.  In other words, CLOSE then OPEN.

Comment: @HansUp, that's something I could try, but ```frmContactDetails``` won't always open FROM ```frmContactList```.  @Brian - tried that and ```frmContactDetails``` doesn't find the proper record and errors out on loading.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you open a form with `WindowMode:=acDialog`, then the code stops at this code line until the opened form is made invisible or closed. Just drop this parameter.

```
DoCmd.OpenForm "frmContactDetails", View:=acNormal, WhereCondition:="[ID]=" & ID
DoCmd.Close acForm, Me.Name
```

Note: Use `WindowMode:=acDialog` if you need the data entered in a dialog form at the call site. In this case, don't close the dialog form with `Me.Close` but instead hide it with `Me.Visible = False`, then get its data through `Forms!fdlgMyDialogForm!TheData.Value` and finally close it at the call site with `DoCmd.Close acForm, "fdlgMyDialogForm"`.

Closing the current form with `Me.Name` is more robust than specifying the name as string constant.